# How to force Windows run only 32bits IE8 rather than the 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2003, 32-bit

I have a Windows Server 2003 64bits, and it has two IE8 inside, 32-bit and 64-bit.

When I run "iexplore.exe", debug in visual studio, clicking links, and etc, the 64-bit will popup and some plugins do not work.

How can I fix my system that it will always run the 32-bit IE by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have "Internet Explorer" and "Internet Explorer (64-bit)" under Start/All Programs. You may examine these shortcuts by right-click and properties, to find how to run each version.

The path to the 32-bits version is probably something like this (I can't verify, not having a 64-bits system):
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`

You can verify that the right version is running in Task Manger, where the running 32-bits process should be shown as `iexplore.exe*32`.

Comment: I know how to choose and how to run them. It is not what I am looking for.

I have to know how to set the default.

Comment: @Dennis: The default browser is defined by the registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command

Comment: @harrymc HKCR\http control only the default application to handle URLs with http protocol. but it is not always the default browser, in some cases.

For example, in older version of MSN messenger, it use OLE/ActiveX/COM+ (whatever you call it) to launch browser. 

I've faced few another cases like that, but I don't recall their name.

Comment: @Dennis: In my case command contains the browser. In any case, I don't see how it can contain an ActiveX or whatever, since these can't be invoked from the command-line.

Answer (score -1):

You can just copy the IExplorer 64 bit from the `Program Files` directory to Internet Explorer 32bit directory at `Program Files (x86)` directory. And that's how you'll get rid of Internet Explorer 32bit.

If it won't let you - just rename the Internet Explorer 32bit directory and copy the 64bit to that directory.

You might need to "Take Ownership" on that directory and maybe remove the "Read Only" from it.

It worked great for me.

Comment: Just terrible advise. Don't do that.